# Почему берутся координаты развернутой формы а не просто координаты формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Почему берутся координаты развернутой формы а не просто координаты формы? Мне нужно взять координаты нижнего правого края формы не зависимо развернута она на весь экран или нет.

```
buttonHide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.DesktopLocation.X + this.Size.Width - 95, this.DesktopLocation.Y + this.Size.Height - 264);
```

Answer (score 1):

Не понял про развернутую форму (ничего подобного я не замечал работая с winforms ранее) - но вижу одну ошибку.

Позиция каждого контрола задается относительно его родителя (точнее, относительно *клиентской области* родителя) - а потому добавление `DesktopLocation` наверняка является ошибкой. Еще одна ошибка - использование `Size` вместо `ClientSize`. Попробуйте вот так:

```
buttonHide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.ClientSize.Width - 95, this.ClientSize.Height - 264);
```

Кстати, если вы пытаетесь перемещать кнопку при изменениях размера формы - то  есть куда более удобный механизм. Просто расположите кнопку в нужном месте и задайте ей якорь (`Anchor`) `Right` | `Bottom` вместо того, который по умолчанию.